# Issue with URI routing so links doesn't work with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, url-routing, href

I'm new to CodeIgniter. I have a homepage with links. I know how to link the homepage with another page, but I think I'm doing something wrong in the routes.php
I looked through the tutorials, but I still can't find the problem. I tried writing the routes in different ways. Can someone help me?

**View of home.php**

```
 <ul>
          <li><a href="home.php">Homepagina</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.php">Over</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('login/login'); ?>">Inloggen</a></li>
            <li><a href="register.php">Registreren</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('myprofile/myuserprofile'); ?>">Profiel</a></li>
            <li><a href="matches.php">Matches</a></li>
            <li><a href="config.php">Config</a></li>
        </ul>
```

**Controller of home.php**

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {
public function view($home ='home')
{
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');

    if (! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$home.'.php'))
    {

        show_404();
    }
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($home);

    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('templates/slideshow', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$home, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);
```

}
}

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] ='pages/view';
$route['login'] = 'login/view/login';
```

**Controller of Login**

```
class Login extends CI_Controller {
public function view($login ='login')
{
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->helper('url');


    if (! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages/'.$login.'.php'))
    {

        show_404();
    }
    $data['title'] = ucfirst($login);

    $this->load->view('templates/header',$data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$login, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer',$data);    
}
```

Thank you for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

just call controller and method

```
<li><a href="login/login">Inloggen</a></li>
```

If not works

```
<li><a href="index.php/login/login">Inloggen</a></li>
```

try this

Comment: thank you for the answer! I solved it: it must be index.php/login

Answer (score 0):

When you extend a class that has a constructor, you need to call that constructor from the class you are extending it from... ie

```
class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); // Call the CI_Controller __construct();
}
```

Note that the __ is actually two underscores but appears a a single line on here.

With your Routes

**routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] ='pages/view';
$route['login'] = 'login/view/login';
```

Remember that a CI URL is of the form domainname.com/controller/method

The default_controller is where the browser will be redirected to if you do not supply the controller/method ie - just domainname.com. With your default controller route, you will be redirecting to your **pages** controller and accessing the **view** method. Going by your code that should be fine.

Your login route should also be fine if you access domainname.com/login as your url - this will be sent to your login controller, view method and passing in login as the page name.

**home.php**

```
 <ul>
   <li><a href="home.php">Homepagina</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.php">Over</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('login/login'); ?>">Inloggen</a></li>
   <li><a href="register.php">Registreren</a></li>
   <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('myprofile/myuserprofile'); ?>">Profiel</a></li>
   <li><a href="matches.php">Matches</a></li>
   <li><a href="config.php">Config</a></li>
 </ul>
```

With your link to home.php, you might want to create a controller called Home.php and define the index() method. So change

```
<a href="home.php">Homepagina</a>
```

to

```
<a href="home">Homepagina</a>
```

The link then becomes domainname.com/home - which points to your **home** controller and it's **index** method.

Then we come to this

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('login/login');
```

This will create **domainname.com/login/login**. Your login route is only looking for **domainname.com/login**. So the current link **domainname.com/login/login** is looking for a Controller called login with a method called login.

Your link with myprofile/myuserprofile will be looking for a controller called **myprofile** and a method called **myuserprofile**. There is nothing in your routes.php to deal with this. So if that is not working, it's nothing to do with the routes.

So this is all pointing back to you (possibly) not having defined the __construct methods as I discussed at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li><a href="index.php/login/login">Inloggen</a></li>
```

if it works you can remove index.php.
follow this documentation to remove [index page](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html?highlight=index%20page#index_page)

Comment: thank you for the answer! I solved it, it must be index.php/login

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use full path of url i.e. starting with `http[s]://`, it's always smart start links with fore slash:

```
<li><a href="/pages/about">Over</a></li>
```

You can use CI url helper and be more safe in case you are struggling™ with .htaccess and index.php with:

```
echo base_url('pages/about')
```

Also, practicing static pages tutorial, pay attention on docs' Loader lybrary page, so you can find how to pass all data to all view pages, leaving it to view files and in that case you don't need to set second parameter in here:

```
$this->load->vars($data);

$this->load->view('templates/header');
$this->load->view('templates/slideshow');
$this->load->view('pages/'.$home);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

And all $data array will be passed to all view files and you'll be able to make output of those. 
Maybe you find it usefull once. ;)

Comment: thak you for the answer and the extra information! :)